# Using Couchbase in background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, background, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am developing an app which uses Couchbase to sync the documents. Right now all the documents I am creating on main thread and using the same.

But now I got stuck in a scenario where I need to create and push the document in some other thread than main, not blocking the UI.

How I can run the part of Couchbase database in background thread to support only above scenario.

Tried the methods in the Couchbase documentation for concurrency support.But receiving the **thread safety crash** crash telling whenever I create documents in the background thread like this.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   //creating couchbase documents here
}
```

Getting below crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '***** THREAD-SAFETY
>   VIOLATION: This database is being used on a thread it wasn't  created
>   on! Please see the concurrency guidelines in the Couchbase Lite
>   documentation. *****

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couchbase Lite APIs in 1.x are not thread safe and support a thread confinement model. So you cannot share objects across threads - In other words, if you created a `CBLDatabase` object on main thread, you cannot use that instance on your background thread. You will have to create a new instance for your background thread. 
So do the following :

- Create a new [serial dispatch queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6)
- Create a `CBLManager` instance
- Set the manager’s `dispatchQueue` property to the queue you created
- Do your Couchbase Lite calls inside `dispatch_async` calls on your queue.

As an aside, Couchbase Mobile 2.0 APIs are thread safe and something you may want to consider if this is a greenfield project.

Comment: Can I use global background queues here or do I need to create only serial queue?

Comment: Chceked.Still I am getting same crash.Do I need to create separate CBLDatabase instance to run the tasks in background thread?

Comment: Now I am getting below crash.  
 *** Assertion failure in -[CBL_FMDatabase beginUse], /Users/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/couchbase-lite-ios-builds/couchbase-lite-ios-community/vendor/fmdb/src/FMDatabase.m:979

Comment: For concurrent queues you need to create a database object each time since there is no thread safety in those.  Don't forget to close it when you are done.

Comment: @borrrden i am working on cblite 2.1.0 and i am facing same issue, database.addchangelistener continusly upating one of the screen irrespective whether i am on that screen or not , so it blocking my ios app ui , could you help me on thi